# KeyError: 'kivy.garden.graph', Kivy app can't launch

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer

I am trying to generate my apk, and I added garden dependency to requirements part in my .spec file as follow:

```
requirements = sqlite3,kivy,kivy_garden.graph
```

But my apk can't be ;aunch, so I run logcat and notice this error.

```
09-08 15:14:43.525  5572  5594 I python  :  KeyError: 'kivy.garden.graph'
09-08 15:14:43.525  5572  5594 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

Can anyone help? Is this method outdated?